# Обособление уточняющего оборота

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Среди многих, достойных положительной оценки, результатов были названы дальнейшее развитие...
Надо ли обособлять оборот "достойных положительной оценки"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Второй ответ** (первый ответ получился длинным, в то время как в принципе задача решается просто).

Предложение: **Среди многих, достойных положительной оценки, результатов были названы: дальнейшее развитие...**

**Решение**

1) Мы имеем **два определения в препозиции**: местоимение  и определительный оборот.

2) Возможны **три варианта решения**: нет запятых (неоднородные отношения), одна запятая (однородные отношения), две запятые (уточнение или пояснение). Примечание: при пояснении иногда пишется одна запятая.

3) Но у нас не пояснение, а именно **уточнение** (конкретизация значения местоименного прилагательного), то есть требуется  **обособление оборота**.

4) **Неоднородные** отношения (отсутствие знаков) возможно при **тесной связи** местоимения и оборота, но такой тесной связи нет.

Обычно тесная связь **местоимения и определительного оборота** возможна для определительных или указательных  местоимений вида ***этот, весь*** (см. примеры Розенталя), а у нас неопределенно-количественное местоимение.

Answer (score 1):

**Среди многих, достойных положительной оценки, результатов были названы: дальнейшее развитие...**

Оборот надо обособить, перед перечислением поставить двоеточие.

1) Это **уточняющий** оборот, конкретизирующий значение местоименного прилагательного ***многие***. (Среди многих результатов, которые достойны положительной оценки...).

2) Для сравнения. Два варианта постановки запятых (одна запятая, две запятых) имеют **пояснительные** определения со значением "а именно", но здесь такого значения нет.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

3) **Примечание. Когда оборот не обособляется**

В некоторых случаях при отсутствии уточняющего или пояснительного значения оборот может не обособляться, но это тоже не наш случай. Нам важно среди многих результатов **ВЫДЕЛИТЬ именно те, которые получили положительную оценку, ** а это можно сделать **только с помощью обособления.**

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108

4. Определительный оборот, стоящий после определительного, указательного или притяжательного местоимения, **тесно примыкает к нему и запятой не отделяется**: (Кор.); Все опоздавшие на лекцию стояли в коридоре; Эти недавно опубликованные стихи были написаны много времени назад (Газ.); Даша ждала всего, но только не этой покорно склонённой головы (А. Т.);

**Но если определительный оборот имеет характер пояснения или уточнения** [см. § 22, п. 4], **то он обособляется (выделяется запятыми).**

Answer (score 1):

**Не обособляются** распространенные определения, стоящие перед существительным и **не имеющие добавочных обстоятельственных оттенков значения**:

*Среди многих достойных положительной оценки результатов были названы дальнейшее развитие...*

**Ср.** *Среди многих **хороших** результатов были названы дальнейшее развитие...*

Для справки: [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108)

Продолжу ответ.

**Обособить это выражение можно, но в этом случае существенно меняется интонация и даже смысл.**

Будучи обособленным, выражение *достойных положительной оценки* функционирует как ***вставная конструкция***: звучит "скороговоркой", с понижением тона, содержит попутное замечание и авторскую оценку, что характерно для вставных конструкций:

*Среди многих, достойных положительной оценки, результатов были названы дальнейшее развитие...* - Или: *Среди многих - достойных положительной оценки - результатов были названы дальнейшее развитие...*

**Так что обособлять или нет - решать автору высказывания.**

Comment: Перед существительным "результатов" у нас два определения: одиночное местоименное прилагательное с количественным значением и  определительный оборот.  В данном случае нет тесного примыкания, нам важно выделить оборот как уточняющий, а это можно сделать только при обособлении оборота.

Comment: Многие хорошие результаты - это ряд хороших результатов (все результаты хорошие), многие результаты - это ряд разных результатов. При обособлении оборота внутри второго ряда мы выделяем только положительные результаты.